# No connection Npgsql from Vb. NET

Tags: postgresql, vb.net

I have problems connecting to PostgresQL using Npgsql. I see this error:

> InnerException = {"Couldn't set old guids (Parameter 'old guids')"}

The ConnectionString is this:

```
"Server = 192.168.XX.XXX; Port = 5432; Database = XXXXX; User Id = postgres; Password = XXXXXX; 
Initial Schema = public; Pooling=true; Min Pool Size =0; Maximum Pool Size=1024; old guids=True"
```

I also tried this connection configuration and several variations and it still gives the error:

```
cs2 = "Server = 192.168.XX.XXX; Port = 5432; Database = XXXXX; User Id = postgres; Password = XXXXXX; 
Initial Schema = public; Pooling=true; Min Pool Size =0; Maximum Pool Size=1024; old guids=True"
```

Here is the VB code:

```
Public ConexionPostSql2 As New NpgsqlConnection(cs2)
Public Function ConectarPostgreSql2() As Boolean
    Try
        System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance)
        ConexionPostSql2.Open()
        ConectarPostgreSql2 = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        ConectarPostgreSql2 = False
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error PostgreSQL")
    End Try
End Function
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The error message tells yous what the issue is. So check the possible connection options from the [doc](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html) and see that there is no `old guids` option.

Comment: An exception is generated. The exception as such returns this message:
InnerException = {"Couldn't set old guids (Parameter 'old guids')"}

Comment: so if it can't be set and it is not an option either, maybe try removing it...

Comment: Why do you think you should be able to set "old guids"? Did you copy that connection string from somewhere? If so, where? It just5 seems odd that the error message is telling you explicitly what the issue is and you just seem to be ignoring that.

Comment: I don't ignore the error. I give it what the connection string asks for and it continues to insist that there is an error. I checked the string against Connectionstrings.com and it reflected that error. I am checking if there is something incorrectly selected in the configuration in the DB. In navicat it connects well but the connection parameters it indicates do not work for me

Comment: @armasgash If you look at [the entry for Npgsql](https://www.connectionstrings.com/npgsql/) on connectionstrings.com, I suggest that you start with the form of the first, simplest, option: `Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;`.

Comment: I already found the solution after thinking around: the connection to PostSQL must be indicated within the function itself and not in a public variable.      Public cs2 = "Server=My Server"         Try
            System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance)
            ConexionPostSql1.ConnectionString = cs2
            ConexionPostSql1.Open()
            ConectarPostgreSql1 = True
        Catch ex As Exception
            ConectarPostgreSql1 = False
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error PostgreSQL")
        End Try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Public cs2 = "My Server"

```
Public Function ConectarPostgreSql1() As Boolean
    Try
        System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance)
        ConexionPostSql1.ConnectionString = cs2
        ConexionPostSql1.Open()
        ConectarPostgreSql1 = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        ConectarPostgreSql1 = False
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error PostgreSQL")
    End Try
End Function
```

For it to work, I had to declare the connection in the same function. Curiously, MySQL does allow it to be done above when declaring the connection (Public ConexionMySql1 As New MySqlConnection(cs1) for example in MSSQL or MySQL work perfect)